# How to run a javascript script from a html form without redirecting the page until the javascript runs and also passing a variable to the js file?

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript. Please point me in the right direction! Also if you think my code is not efficient that is ok to tell me to.

I have this home page that takes the user's full name and I want to pass into the javascript and save it as a variable. The javascript returns an url back to the first page and then it gets redirected.

Here is the HTML I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

     <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/indexstyle.css" />
</head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" method="GET" action="create.js">
            <p>Please type your name:</p>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="textbox" name="username" required = "" placeholder="Type Your First and Last Name" autofocus><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Join" class="orangebutton"><br>
        </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

The javascript has a variable that is named username = "".

I appreciate any help and direction pointing.

Comment: While the `javascript` runs the browser is blocked and nothing will happen (no redirects, no animations, no nothing).

Comment: The `action` for a form has to be a server-side script, not a `.js` file. If you want to process the form in the browser, you need to load the JS into the script immediately. It can then use event handlers.